# How to change default editor of oracle 9i?

Tags: oracle9i

I am using Oracle 9i ,when i type ed ,notepad gets open ,i want to use Microsoft Word instead of notepad as an editor,Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

I would **not** advise using MS Word as a text editor, as it adds a lot of proprietary formatting junk that SQL Plus will not understand.  However, you can specify any editor you like in SQL Plus using this command:

```
define _editor = "<path to editor>"
```

For example, I use TextPad:

```
define _editor = "C:\Program Files\TextPad 5\TextPad.exe"
```

For Word I would have to write:

```
define _editor = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\Winword.exe"
```

You can put this in a login.sql file on the default folder so that it runs automatically whenever you start SQL Plus